# Why is the contour of a stream function the same as the streamline?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acoustics, vector-fields, flow

I am studying acoustic streamlines. As this paper [Singular points of intensity streamlines in two-dimensional sound fields](https://asa.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1121/1.418034)

says

[image]

the level curves or contours of stream function represents the intensity streamline (the sentence below Eq(6)).

But how to understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2D [stream function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_function) $\psi$ is constant along a streamline because the gradient $\nabla \psi$ by definition (5) is perpendicular to the flow ${\bf I}$.